# What type of bush is this?

Tags: identification

Maybe you can help, I love this bush because there is absolutely no way to kill it.  Maybe it's a 'superman' bush?  It has long sharp thorny branches and in the late fall produces an impressive fruit that reminds me of a small apple.

I want to transplant in a fence row but would like to know what exactly it is.  If it helps, I live in Central Ohio (zone 6 I think).

[image]

Thank You[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imn45.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *Chaenomeles* possibly *Chaenomeles x superba 'Pink Lady*. The most commonly seen variety is *Chaenomeles japonica* but they usually have red flowers. It is often known as japanese or flowering quince because of the quince like fruits it produces in autumn/fall, which can be used to make quince jelly/jam instead of the true quince  (*Cydonia oblongata*). *Chaenomeles* though are more usually grown for their attractive flowers in spring rather than the fruits. Further information here https://www.ballyrobertgardens.com/products/chaenomeles-x-superba-pink-lady

Comment: Thank You Very Much!  Could it be a 'Chaenomeles Speciosa'?  The fruit is definitely like a quince.

Comment: 'speciosa;'  flowers are more red than pink though, but yea, maybe...